# How to turn off PowerShell notification

Tags: powershell, adobe-photoshop

How to turn off this pop-up PowerShell notification that appears at start-up?

[image: Start up pop-up for PowerShell]

When trying to install Photoshop from torrents, I had to disable Windows real time Defender, and the msvcr100.dll file was missing.

I got both .dll files from dll-files.com.

I incorrectly replaced the msvcp110.dll file, but figured out my mistake soon enough and put back the original file. When installing Photoshop it didn't work, so I replaced both the new .dlls with the original files. Now my computer is asking me to do click yes every time I start my computer up.

I would appreciate any answers or just a way to stop me from clicking the Yes button in the PowerShell pop-up all the time.

Nksvoo is causing my problems:

[image: Nksvoo causing my problems]

Comment: Uninstall the software you installed that had added a startup entry that launches PowerShell.  You should have just ask us how to solve the missing msvcr100.dll file problem.  Your actions have caused more problems than it solved.  Provide a screenshot of Autoruns show which startup entities your system has.  You can [edit] your question

Comment: Thank you so much, Ramhound! I found the Nksvoo.dll that was running and disabled it on startup. Then I deleted it from my computer along with the folder it was in, MardikSvoO. It was in the AppData\Roaming folder. When I restarted it worked! no more popup notifications. Thank you again!

Comment: MardikSvoO doesn’t sound like legitimate software

Comment: You're right! It wasn't a software, it was the folder: C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\MardikSvoO\Nksvoo.dll
I opened up the startup in task manager and disabled it. Don't really know how to delete it but it's alright I think. When I right click on it, there's two options to enable or search online. I searched online, it runs a bing search for "rundll32.exe Nksvoo".

Comment: You downloaded an infected product.